# Firefox acts weird when toggling an element while in chrome it works fine

Tags: jquery

Here's the example: http://jsbin.com/ovupuq/3

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var cursor = $("<span>_</span>").appendTo("p"),
          blik = function(){
                  $(cursor).toggle(200);
                };
      setInterval(blik,500);
});
```

The problem is that the "Hello World!" text bumps everytime the cursor is toggled. This happens only in firefox 11, chrome and IE8 work as expected.

Another thing I notice is that if I have this running for a couple minutes the 500ms interval I set seems to change into some random values, which makes the cursor blink faster. This happens only in chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### *[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/iqimiz/2/edit#javascript,html,live)*

- Just remove `200` from `toggle`
- You have already defined your cursor `element` using `$()` so just use: `cursor`

---

```
var cursor = $("<span>_</span>").appendTo("p"),
    blik = function(){ cursor.toggle(); };
setInterval(blik,500);
```

(In your code: while the toggle was rinning at 200, your Interval '500' at some time was messing with the toggle function creating event bubblings)